# Retrieving Filter items in P13nFilterPanel

Tags: sapui5

We are using a `P13nFilterPanel`. When pressing the `[+]` button, to add a new filter item, we see the added items on the gui, but can not retrieve the values. How do we retrieve the filter items? We are bound to a JSON object for the original items.

Comment: can you add how you are trying to retrieve? Did you try `getFilterItems()`?

Comment: the new items will be added directly into your jsonmodel

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We tried getFilterItems(), and although we see the components on the screen, this function does not return the additional items. Ash - I agree the items should automatically be attached to the json

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method getConditions() of your sap.m.P13nFilterPanel object.

Something like

```
p13nOk: function(oEvent) { var aConditions = oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[0].getConditions();
            console.log(aConditions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the method say `addfilter` in your controller using this `addFilterItem="addfilter"` property of `<P13nFilterPanel>` from your `view.xml`.

The method `addfilter` will get called everytime you add a filter item.
In that method retrieve the values of the filter added from the event that got triggered.

I was facing the same issue, this worked for me.